# That's where past/present-tense

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

The bag where I buy at the shop is missing.
The bag where I bought at the shop is missing. 
Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Neither, the correct answer is "The bag *that* I bought at the shop is missing."

Comment: Ahh, I see.. Thank you!!